# In TS, question mark after defined method name

Tags: typescript

I understand use of TS `?` for declare optional params, fields, optional methods, etc. But I seen code that put `?` after method that is defined in class, like this:

```
class Foo {
  public myMethod?(...) {
    ... code
  }
}
```

Why this is useful?

Comment: This will allow to do some strange things as `new Foo().myMethod = undefined;`

Comment: @AlekseyL.: thanks, i suppose that true. Is this useful realistically?

Comment: I can't think about any good example for this 

Comment: You say you've seen code that does it.  Where?

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into this today. The `?` after a method allows an implementing class to *not* implement that method. That is to say, implementing that method is optional.
Can be done for interfaces or classes. If you choose to implement the optional method, you do not need to add the `?` unless it is intended for a subsequent implementation to also be optional.

Here's a contrived example

```
export interface Foo {
    bar(): string;
    baz?(): string;
}

// Buzz can implement gazz optionally
export class Buzz implements Foo {
    readonly gar: string;

    readonly jazz: string;

    constructor() {
        this.gar = 'GAR!';
        this.jazz = 'jazz!';
    }

    bar() {
        return this.gar;
    }

    gazz() { // no ? means subsequent implementations need gazz
        return this.jazz;
    }
}

// Stuzz needs to implement method gazz, but does not
export class Stuzz implements Buzz {
    readonly gar: string;

    readonly jazz: string;

    constructor() {
        this.gar = 'ZAR!';
        this.jazz = 'jazz!';
    }

    bar() {
        return this.gar;
    }

  /**
   * Without gazz we get an error:
   * Class 'Stuzz' incorrectly implements class 'Buzz'. Did you mean to extend 'Buzz' and inherit its members as a subclass?
   * Property 'gazz' is missing in type 'Stuzz' but required in type 'Buzz'.
   */
    // gazz() {
    //     return this.jazz;
    // }
}
```

Comment: A concrete example of this is [ApolloServerPlugins](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/), which allow you to define callback methods that are invoked for various events. For the [TypeScript ApolloServerPlugin interface](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server-plugin-base/src/index.ts#L56), all of the methods are defined as optional. That allows a plugin to only implement methods for events that it needs. If they weren't optional, every plugin would have to implement every method.